# PhD in X needed for academic career in X

Tags: phd, career-path, europe

I am based in Europe, and I am about to start my PhD. Europe refers to the set of countries I may want to work in: Germany, Switzerland, France, Austria.

> Is it formally necessary that I earn it in field X if I want to have an academic career in field X?

By academic career I mean taking up a professorship, or in any case, a research position in some university.

Assuming that my research falls significantly under field Y as well, what disadvantages may happen in trying to have an academic career in Y?

What about X = mechanical engineering (focus computational mechanics) and Y = mathematics (focus numerical methods) ?

Comment: This question isn't answerable, it's too general. The answer is field-specific.

Comment: @user438383 Updated

Comment: Still not answerable and too general @hahn76

Comment: @Starship-OnStrike Can you please indicate what clarifications should I address?

Comment: What job are you talking about for one? Certain jobs wont care about your schooling, pust your performance whilst others tend to be the opposite (and theres of course some in the middle) @hahn76

Comment: Hopefully it is more answerable now. I cannot be more precise as for the country. @Starship-OnStrike

Comment: We still need to know what profession @hahn76

Comment: "By academic career I mean taking up a professorship, or in any case, a research position in some university." @Starship-OnStrike. I mean to be a university researcher, possibly professor, in on of the two mentioned fields. I don't know how to further detail from here.

Comment: Okay I think thats enough detail then thanks @hahn76

Comment: While a PhD in Italian literature is likely a barrier to employment in an engineering faculty, much of STEM is highly interrelated and the specifics of what you studied and how it applies to what is happening in some department is the most relevant question.

Comment: What is wrong with Austria and Belgium :D ?

Comment: @EarlGrey - well, for Belgium at least, mayonnaise on fries for one...

Comment: Well right, added Austria, Belgium is too far away from where I live ;)

Comment: Glad you got a useful answer. I can't imagine this post being useful for anyone else in the future, so I'm going to close it out for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Europe is not a country.

In some European countries, the PhD in topic X (say engineering) preclude you from being professor in department of Y (say mathematics). Some countries have granular divisions of topics, and some topics fit (are allowed to apply towards) a certain faculty, some another faculty.

However, what you ask is a bit non-sense.
You can simply be Xy, a PhD in Mechanical Engineering, with a focus on numerical methods applied to computational mechanics. With that knowledge you will have plenty of opportunities, in the academia and outside, in any country as long as you learn the local language (and even without knowing the language you can find something).

Comment: +1 for "Europe is not a country", Iceland, the UK, and Greece are all in Europe